# Create XML from input parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to write storedProcedure in sqlserver2008, this proc Must be inserted in a tables(Users, roles, groups,...),1 other proc insert into users table,I Call this and need to write my proc whit xml input parameter and call adduser proc in this, how to get xml parameter and use in my proc?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SaveInvoice]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@XMLHD XML,@XMLDT XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HDOUT INT 
    DECLARE @DTOUT INT
    declare @maxcode int
    CREATE TABLE #MESSAGE (MID SMALLINT,MMESSAGE VARCHAR(200))

```
EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @HDOUT OUTPUT,@XMLHD
EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @DTOUT OUTPUT,@XMLDT


SELECT *into #hd FROM OPENXML(@HDOUT,'HEAD',1) 
  WITH(invoiceno VARCHAR(500),customercode INT,invDate Date);

SELECT * into #dt FROM OPENXML(@DTOUT,'SAVE/INVOIEC',1)
      WITH(No INT,ItemCode INT,Qty DECIMAL(18,2),Rate Decimal(18,2),Amount Decimal(18,2));

      IF EXISTS (SELECT invInvoiceNO FROM dbo.trnInvoiceHD WHERE invInvoiceNO IN (SELECT invoiceno FROM #hd) )
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MESSAGE
     SELECT 1,'iNVOICE NO ALREADYEXIST'        
     SELECT * FROM #MESSAGE MESSAGE FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS XSINIL
    RETURN
    END

select @maxcode=isnull(max(invhdcode),0)+1 from dbo.trnInvoiceHD     

 begin try 
 begin transaction
insert into dbo.trnInvoiceHD(invhdcode,invInvoiceNO,invDate,invCusCode)
select @maxcode,invoiceno,invDate,customercode from #hd 

insert into dbo.trnInvoiceDt(invDtTrncode,invdtSlNo,invdtitemcode,invDtRate,invDtQty,invDtAmount)
select @maxcode,No,ItemCode,Rate,Qty,Amount from #dt 

     INSERT INTO #MESSAGE
     SELECT 1,'SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED'

   SELECT * FROM #MESSAGE MESSAGE FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS XSINIL

commit transaction
end try

begin Catch
rollback transaction
INSERT INTO #MESSAGE
     SELECT 1,ERROR_MESSAGE ()         
     SELECT * FROM #MESSAGE MESSAGE FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS XSINIL    
end Catch
```